# npm audit fix --force doesn't solve the issues

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-audit

I have a rect project created a while ago with `react-create-app`. Running `npm install` gives gives me `31 vulnerabilities (24 low, 3 moderate, 4 high)`.
Here are the files that might help debug the issue:

[warnings after running `npm audit fix --force`](https://ucarecdn.com/52b9e237-b730-4b44-8835-974076848ae7/error)

[package.json](https://ucarecdn.com/39a4b046-f7f5-4a82-90e3-87f5027ac47b/package.json)

[package-lock.json](https://ucarecdn.com/918b3458-5d3b-4797-9894-bab4ff0f561f/packagelock.json)

I tried:

- Deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install`. Still the exact same issues remain.
- Updating all of my packages to the latest with `npm-check-updates`.
- Clearing npm chache with `npm cache clear --force`

None of these solved any of the issues.

PS: Creating a brand new project with `npx create-react-app` has the exact same problem, so it is not related to my specific app it's some global issue.

Comment: I tried to click on the link to your `package.json`, but it says "File not found".
(The other two links are not needed. The `package.json` is all it takes to make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)